# How to fill div with image in devices with max width 480?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I created this [page](http://hmahdavi.zgig.ir/forQuestion/HTMLPage1.html) .I am trying to display images with 100% with in devices with max width 480. I set `width` of images to `100%` and `height` of it to `auto` But images don't fill parent div.Please advice

```
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />


    <title></title>

    <!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">-->

    <link href="bootstrap_Cerulean.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>



<body  dir="rtl">

<div class="row image-box style2">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <article class="box">
                                <figure class="animated fadeInLeft" data-animation-type="fadeInLeft" data-animation-duration="1" style="animation-duration: 1s; visibility: visible;">
                                    <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://placehold.it/270x192" alt=""></a>
                                </figure>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <h4>Hire Cars</h4>
                                    <p>Nunc cursus libero purus ac congue ar lorem cursus ut sed vitae pulvinar massa idend porta nequetiam elerisque mi id.</p>
                                    <a href="#" title="" class="button">SEE ALL</a>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <article class="box">
                                <figure class="animated fadeInLeft" data-animation-type="fadeInLeft" data-animation-duration="1" data-animation-delay="0.4" style="animation-duration: 1s; animation-delay: 0.4s; visibility: visible;">
                                    <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://placehold.it/270x192" alt=""></a>
                                </figure>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <h4>Cruise Deals</h4>
                                    <p>Nunc cursus libero purus ac congue ar lorem cursus ut sed vitae pulvinar massa idend porta nequetiam elerisque mi id.</p>
                                    <a href="#" title="" class="button">SEE ALL</a>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <article class="box">
                                <figure class="animated fadeInLeft" data-animation-type="fadeInLeft" data-animation-duration="1" style="animation-duration: 1s; visibility: visible;">
                                    <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://placehold.it/270x192" alt=""></a>
                                </figure>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <h4>Things To Do</h4>
                                    <p>Nunc cursus libero purus ac congue ar lorem cursus ut sed vitae pulvinar massa idend porta nequetiam elerisque mi id.</p>
                                    <a href="#" title="" class="button">SEE ALL</a>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <article class="box">
                                <figure class="animated" data-animation-type="fadeInLeft" data-animation-duration="1" data-animation-delay="0.4">
                                    <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://placehold.it/270x192" alt=""></a>
                                </figure>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <h4>Fly in Comfort</h4>
                                    <p>Nunc cursus libero purus ac congue ar lorem cursus ut sed vitae pulvinar massa idend porta nequetiam elerisque mi id.</p>
                                    <a href="#" title="" class="button">SEE ALL</a>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the `head` of your HTML page (very important, fixes media queries):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

In the CSS on your cited page, I noticed that there is this style which is causing you problems:

```
.image-box.style2 figure {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}
```

To do what you want, and override that style, add this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .image-box.style2 figure {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

    .row.image-box > div {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

That way the image will not be forced to float left and will not be confined to 250px when the screen is under 480px wide. Also, now there will not be a 15px gap on the left of the screen when the screen is that small.

Comment: What you did with the `width: 100%; height: auto;` on the `img` is correct :)